# Remove category text suffix from product title (magento 2.3)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am a database guy and I am asked to find how to remove breadcrumb category text from product title in the products detail page of a Magento 2 website.

I don't know where the files reside to modify this behavior, I think the ultimo theme is being used.

Any help would be appreciated to remove the category suffix from product title

Thanks in advance!

[image: t n]

Comment: this is not the default behavior. someone actually put effort into displaying this. Can you ask a person that worked on this project previously?

Comment: that person is gone. This has something to do with breadcrumbs, this only shows when breadcrumbs are there

Answer (score 0):

hey below file is responsible to show title :

> /app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/title.phtml (Overide this file in your theme)

please check this file in your theme (replace Custom/Theme with your theme name)

else we can achieve this by overide the Block **Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title**

Create a module :

> /app/code/Custom/module/etc/di.xml

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" type="Custom\Module\Block\Html\Title" />
</config>`

> /app/code/Custom/Module/Block/Html/Title.php

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Title extends Template
{

    protected $pageTitle;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->registry = $registry;    
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {      
        if($this->registry->registry('current_product')) {
            return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        }
        return false;        
    }
}
```

> /app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/title.phtml

```
<?php
$prodcut = $block->getCurrentProduct();
$cssClass = $block->getCssClass() ? ' ' . $block->getCssClass() : '';
$title = '';
if (trim($block->getPageHeading())) {
    if($prodcut){ 
    $title = '<span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" ' .  $block->getAddBaseAttribute() . '>'
        . 'SOMETEXT '.$block->escapeHtml($block->getPageHeading()) . '</span>';
    }else{
    $title = '<span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" ' .  $block->getAddBaseAttribute() . '>'
        . $block->escapeHtml($block->getPageHeading()) . '</span>';
    }
}
?>
<?php if ($title): ?>
<div class="page-title-wrapper<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $cssClass ?>">
    <h1 class="page-title"
        <?php if ($block->getId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getId() ?>" <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()): ?>
            aria-labelledby="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddBaseAttributeAria() ?>"
        <?php endif; ?>>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?>
    </h1>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

With $product variable we can add condition to check product page.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, i could only find gtm_body.phtml and gtm_head.phtml under
/srv/public_html/app/design/frontend/Bixlers/enhanced/Magento_Theme/templates/html

Comment: ans updated please review

Comment: can u connect on linkedIn ? i have sent a connection request